# Show number of similar records in sql recordset

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a table with fields createdate, a,b,c,d,e. i would like to create a resultset that shows the following:

createdate,a,b,c,d,e, [number of records created in last 10 minutes with same b,c,d

Comment: Which database are you using?  (SQL Server, MySQL, ...?)

Comment: Is it 10 minutes from last insert with same values (b, c, d) or 10 minutes from "now"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    createdate,
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d,
    e,
    duplicatesCount = 
    (
        SELECT count(*) as c
        FROM Table as t2
        WHERE DATEADD(minute, 10, t1.createdate) > GETDATE()
           AND t2.b = t1.b AND t2.c = t1.c AND t2.d = t1.c
    )
    FROM Table as t1
```

Comment: don't you mean last condition in where as 't2.d = t1.d'

Answer (score 0):

```
select  *
,       (
        select  count(*)
        from    YourTable yt2
        where   yt1.b = yt2.b
                and yt1.c = yt2.c
                and yt1.d = yt2.d
                and yt2.createdate between 
                    yt1.createdate - interval 10 minute
                    and yt1.createdate
        ) as DuplicateCount
from    YourTable yt1
```

The `yt1.createdate - interval 10 minute` syntax is for MySQL.  For SQL Server, use `dateadd(minute, -10, yt1.createdate)`.